# ctrl-backspace behaves differently across emacs environments, though .init file is same

Tags: spacemacs, indentation, osx

I recently needed to start using another mac for work and I wanted to duplicate my spacemacs settings onto my new computer.  I simply copied all files located in .emacs onto my new computer, and it seems to be working smoothly (I probably got lucky).  There's just one small problem: on my old computer, ctrl-BACKSPACE removes whitespace to the point of the next indentation.  For example, in json:

```
{ 

  "name": "David",
     "job": "",   
}
```

Typing ctrl-BACKSPACE when the cursor is in front of "job" will result in the following (desired)

```
{ 

  "name": "David",
  "job": "",   
}
```

But on my new computer (same OS), it results in the following:

```
{ 

    "name": ""job": "",   
}
```

So it looks like a whole line is being deleted.

Is there an easy fix to make sure the indentation is respected?

I believe the indentation settings are determined by flycheck.  I can give my .init file if it will be helpful.

On the working computer, ctrl-backspace is bound to the following:

```
<C-backspace> runs the command clean-aindent--bsunindent (found in
clean-aindent-mode--keymap), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘clean-aindent-mode.el’.

It is bound to <C-backspace>, M-DEL.

(clean-aindent--bsunindent ARG)

Unindents.
Bound to ‘M-backspace’ key. Searches lines backward, finds the one that
is indented less than the current one. Unindents current line to
align with that smaller indentation

[back]
```

On the new computer, ctr-backspace is bound to the following:

```
<C-backspace> runs the command backward-kill-word (found in global-map), which
is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.

It is bound to <C-backspace>, M-DEL.

(backward-kill-word ARG)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 22.1.

Kill characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times.

[back]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `C-h k` to find out what function `<C-Backspace>` is bound to on the two computers.

After troubleshooting, the solution turns out to be that `clean-aindent-mode` is not installed on the non-working machine.

Comment: I updated my question with the results of running those commands on the respective computers.

Comment: Looks like you typed backspace instead of control-backspace, so that doesn't really tell us much. Also, the second one was in the help buffer at the time, where the key bindings are different. Make sure that you run `C-h k` from the file you were editing where the problem occurs.

Comment: Oops!  Just updated my question with the correct key.

Comment: Good, now we can see the difference. On the working computer it says "<C-backspace> runs the command clean-aindent--bsunindent (found in
clean-aindent-mode--keymap)", while on the non-working one it says "<C-backspace> runs the command backward-kill-word (found in global-map)". So on the non-working computer you probably haven't installed (or enabled) `clean-aindent-mode`. Run `M-x list-packages` and see if it's listed as installed or available.

Comment: thanks, that did it.  I'll give you the bounty when it's available.

Comment: IMO, you should add the comments with the details of the troubleshooting to your answer: the OP will disagree of course, but the details of what's wrong are unimportant, basically just an accident, whereas the *method* you used to figure it out is much more generally valuable. Nice job BTW!